# How do create a loop that triggers code. in which time index i is X and every X + Y * i loop?

Tags: symbolic-math

I have a scenario where I want to trigger some code on turn 2, and after that every 5th turn.

So I've been experimenting with modulus but cannot seem to get it. Can it be solved like I've attempted below or should I do something completely different?

Comment: Where is you attempt?

Answer (score 0):

try this:
% - modulo returns what's left after dividing. you can compare this mod to 'i' and check if that rest is equal 0.

```
    int x = 2;
    int y = 5;
    int limit = 100;

    for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++){
        if(i == x || (i-x)%y == 0 && i>x) {
            scenario(i);
        }
    }   

public static void scenario(int i){
    System.out.println("Number:" + i);
}
```

result: Number:2, Number:7, Number:12, Number:17 . . .